# How to exclude the event which bubbled from it child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <div id="a">"hahah"</div>
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    padding-left:100px;
}

$('#wrapper').on('mousemove', (e)=>{

    console.log(e.offsetX);
})
```

For instance, When the mouse moving over the element div#a from left to right, the console would print 0, but what I want is that the console should print 100, according to it parent element div#wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get [`event.pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) property to get the relative position based on the whole document.

```
console.log(e.pageX);
```

```js
$('#wrapper').on('mousemove', (e) => {
  console.log(e.pageX);
})
```

```css
#wrapper {
    padding-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div id="a">"hahah"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** To get the position within the `div` subtract its offset from the horizontal position.

```
$('#wrapper').on('mousemove', (e) => {
  console.log(e.pageX - $('#wrapper').offset().left);
})
```

```js
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$wrapper.on('mousemove', (e) => {
  console.log(e.pageX - $wrapper.offset().left);
})
```

```css
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 100px;
  margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div id="a">"hahah"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but what I want is based on #wrapper...If I add margin to #wrapper, your solution wouldnt work ...

Comment: @胡亚雄 : I think this would be the only way :)